# PDO Error - column cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run this PHP PDO Query:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("INSERT into reseller (company, title, forename, surname, address, phone, email, account, bill_by_email, bill_by_post, bill_by_sms, sms_phone, callplan, linked_customer, upload_invoices, show_itemised_calls, support_tickets, support_tickets_emails) values (:company, :title, :forename, :surname, :address, :phone, :email, :account, :bill_by_email, :bill_by_post, :bill_by_sms, :sms_phone, :callplan, :linked_customer, :upload_invoices, :show_itemised_calls, :support_tickets, :support_tickets_emails) ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':company' => ($_POST["company"]), 
    ':title' => ($_POST["title"]), 
    ':forename' => ($_POST["forename"]), 
    ':surname' => ($_POST["surname"]), 
    ':address' => ($_POST["address"]), 
    ':phone' => ($_POST["phone"]), 
    ':email' => ($_POST["email"]), 
    ':account' => ($_POST["account"]), 
    ':bill_by_email' => ($_POST["bill_by_email"]), 
    ':bill_by_post' => ($_POST["bill_by_post"]), 
    ':bill_by_sms' => ($_POST["bill_by_sms"]), 
    ':sms_phone' => ($_POST["sms_phone"]), 
    ':callplan' => ($_POST["callplan"]), 
    ':linked_customer' => ($_POST["linked_customer"]), 
    ':upload_invoices' => ($_POST["upload_invoices"]), 
    ':show_itemised_calls' => ($_POST["show_itemised_calls"]), 
    ':support_tickets' => ($_POST["support_tickets"]), 
    ':support_tickets_emails' => ($_POST["support_tickets_emails"]) ));
```

But i receive this error when i have blank fields:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'bill_by_post' cannot be null' in /home/integra/public_html/lifeline/reseller/addreseller.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /home/integra/public_html/lifeline/reseller/addreseller.php(34): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/integra/public_html/lifeline/reseller/addreseller.php on line 34
```

Whats the best way to stop this from happening? Is it better to use `bindParam()` instead?

Thanks

Comment: Allow Null value for the `bill_by_post` field in your database.

Comment: or check if bill_by_post is set before insert if it cant be NULL

Comment: it is not PDO error but apparently mysql error translated to you by pdo

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- change your fields to allow NULL
- check a value is set before you try to use it
- change your database fields to have some sort of default value; even if that value is an empty string, e.g. `bill_by_post NOT NULL DEFAULT ''` (or equivalent, depending on the data type you're working with)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that column requires a value in the database, and the var you sent is null /empty.

Change it on the dbase or retrieve an error whenever the $_POST["value"] is empty, so the user knows he has to fill the gap, and don't even send it or you'll get an error like you do.

No, answering your question, if in the database you set some requirements, then the data you insert has to match those requirements, otherwise it'll return a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

You can strictly assign your each column variables:

```
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':title' => (string)($_POST["title"]), 
    ':number' => (int)($_POST["number"])
    ));
```

> [PHP Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)